# PhoneGap Build - BlackBerry link doesn't work

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I'm new to mobile development and I've compiled my app through the online PhoneGap Build.

It returns me the links to download all the apps, but the BlackBerry
link doesn't work properly, even if phonegap doesn't return me
any sort of error.
The link is only a single jad file. There are no .jar or .cod files,
and if I try to install it on a blackberry, I can't.

What am I doing wrong?
I don't know much about BlackBerry apps, so maybe I miss something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

on your desktop computer, go to https://build.phonegap.com/apps, and click the name of your app (not the d/l links)

it will show a list of qr codes, one for each platform

on your blackberry, open App World, menu, scan a barcode, then scan the qr code and it will download it like a normal app

Answer (score 0):

That same issue would occasionally happen to me as well.  I resolved it each time by deleting the app in PhoneGap Build and then resubmitting it and then waiting for the build notification to be shown instead of continually hitting refresh in the browser.  It's not scientific but it's what resolved the issue the last 2 times for myself.